# Finding the powershell CIM equivalent to columns from sys.dm_os_sys_info

Tags: sql-server, powershell, wmi

I have a normal SQL Server select that I do which collects information from these two columns from a dynamic management view:

```
SELECT cpu_count, hyperthread_ratio
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

I am wondering if anyone knows of the precise equivalent through a powershell CIM system hardware class? Something like:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Processor
```

But I don't know enough about PC architecture to know which property (or logic based on other properties) from this directly equate to cpu_count and hyperthread_ratio from that sql dmv.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$CPUData = @(Get-CIMInstance -Class Win32_Processor | Select NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors)
$CPU_Count = ($CPUData.NumberOfLogicalProcessors | Measure -Sum).Sum
[pscustomobject]@{'CPU_Count' = $CPU_Count
                  'Hyperthread_Ratio' = $CPU_Count/$CPUData.Count
                }
```

**Explanation:**

`Get-CIMInstance -Class Win32_Processor` returns the properties `NumberOfLogicalProcessors` and `NumberOfCores`. When those two property values are different, then hyperthreading is enabled.

`cpu_count` and `hyperthread_ratio` only return data about the logical CPUs so that's all that we care about for the calculation.

The data you want doesn't exist without a calculation (that I could find). The `cpu_count` is the total number of logical processors (sum of `NumberOfLogicalProcessors` values). `hyperthread_ratio` is the total logical processors divided by the total CPU socket count.

As an aside, my testing shows that processor affinity within the SQL instance does not affect the calculation or the data in the SQL query.